# Text processing using shell script

Tags: shell

I am new to shell script.
I have a text file which consist of some text along with some email ids . now i have to write a shell script to find all email ids.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty approach to reading all email address in a file and then printing them to stdout:

```
#!/bin/bash

ifn=${1:-emfile.txt}  # the first arguments is the filename

# test that it is readable or exit
[ -r "$ifn" ] || {
    printf "error: file open failed '%s'\n" "$ifn"
    exit 1
}

# parse all emails in file and write to stdout
grep -i -o '[A-Z0-9._%+-]\+@[A-Z0-9.-]\+\.[A-Z]\{2,4\}' <"$ifn"

exit 0
```

**input**

```
$ cat emailfile.txt
jon@mickeys.com
Jane@joestonight.org
some@more.com
just some text
```

**output**

```
$ bash parseemail.sh emailfile.txt
jon@mickeys.com
Jane@joestonight.org
some@more.com
```